# Raw types warning (updated)

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Upd: I see that my question is duplicate and my problem is: this is not safe to use generics in arrays. But how do I need to change my code to fix this? All I came up is (and I even doesn't know if this code is similar to old)

```
_readWriteThreads = (ReadWriteThread<T, RP, SP>[]) Array.newInstance(ReadWriteThread.class, sc.getSelectorThreadCount());
```

But this code also gave me a warning.

---

Previous post ([Raw types warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500859/raw-types-warning)):

I'm not a java developer, but I want to fix the only warning in my project in this part of code:

```
public abstract class SelectorThread<T extends MMOConnection<T, RP, SP>, RP extends ReceivablePacket<T, RP, SP>, SP extends SendablePacket<T, RP, SP>>
{
    protected static final Log _log = new MMOLogger(SelectorThread.class, 1000);

    private final AcceptorThread<T, RP, SP> _acceptorThread;
    private final ReadWriteThread<T, RP, SP>[] _readWriteThreads;


    protected SelectorThread(SelectorConfig sc, IPacketHandler<T, RP, SP> packetHandler) throws IOException
    {
        _acceptorThread = new AcceptorThread<T, RP, SP>("AcceptorThread", this, sc);
        _readWriteThreads = new ReadWriteThread[sc.getSelectorThreadCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < _readWriteThreads.length; i++)
            _readWriteThreads[i] = new ReadWriteThread<T, RP, SP>("ReadWriteThread-" + (i + 1), this, sc, packetHandler);
    }

    ...
}
```

The warning:

```
Type safety: The expression of type ReadWriteThread[] needs unchecked
conversion to conform to ReadWriteThread<T,RP,SP>[]
```

Please, can someone help me fix this, or tell me what I must know to fix this. I understand that line above is fixed by `<T, RP, SP>`, but this doesn't work with array.

Comment: Use an `ArrayList<ReadWriteThread<T, RP, SP>>` instead of trying to use an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays and generics don't play well together. You can make them work, just about, but it's a lot of effort.

A much better solution is to use a `List`, probably an `ArrayList`, for which generics "just work":

```
private final List<ReadWriteThread<T, RP, SP>> _readWriteThreads;
```

initialize it using

```
_readWriteThreads = new ArrayList<>();
```

then

```
_readWriteThreads.add(
    new ReadWriteThread<T, RP, SP>("ReadWriteThread-" + (i + 1), this, sc, packetHandler));
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code seems to be incomplete: how I should initialize _readWriteThreads in constructor before adding elements?

Comment: When I try this: `_readWriteThreads = new List<ReadWriteThread<T, RP, SP>>();` I got error `Cannot instantiate the type List<ReadWriteThread<T,RP,SP>>`

Comment: Ok, I got it. I just should use `_readWriteThreads = new ArrayList<ReadWriteThread<T, RP, SP>>();`